# Monitor asynchronous tasks, tracking their running times

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, asynchronous, benchmarking

Scenario: I'm getting requests through a (thread-safe) queue. Each request then needs to be handled in a separate thread. There is a chance that the function (which is actually calling a Java-program via `popen`, and polling its output) takes a very long time.  From the main thread I need a mechanism to indicate that situation (basically, measuring thread-running-time).

In my example I'm trying to 'enrich' `std::future` with some time information. The sample runs seamlessly - but I'm uncertain if this is the correct way.

Here is a very simple demo that mimics what I'm trying to achieve (where `ThreadFunc` stands in for my real processing code):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <random>


typedef std::future<int> FutureResultInt;

int ThreadFunc( )
{
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 mt(rd());

  const int iRand = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(2000, 6000)(mt);

  std::cout << "ThreadFunc waiting for [" << iRand << "] ms ... " << std::endl;

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(iRand));

  std::cout << "ThreadFunc [" << iRand << "] done" << std::endl;

  return iRand;
}

class CFutureTest
{
public:
  CFutureTest() = delete;

  CFutureTest(FutureResultInt&& fr)
    : m_start(std::chrono::system_clock::now())
    , m_result()
  {
    m_result = std::move(fr);
  };

  int GetAge() const
  {
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - m_start).count();
  }

// private:
  FutureResultInt m_result;
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> m_start; 
};

int main()
{
  std::vector< CFutureTest > futures;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    futures.push_back(std::move(std::async(std::launch::async, ThreadFunc)));

  while (futures.size() > 0)
  {
    for (std::vector< CFutureTest >::iterator it = futures.begin(); it != futures.end(); ++it)
    {
      CFutureTest& future = *it;

      const std::future_status stat = future.m_result.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));

      switch (stat)
      {
      case std::future_status::timeout:
        if (future.GetAge() > 4000)
        {
            std::cout << "Thread has exceeded the time limit" << std::endl;
        }
        continue;

      case std::future_status::deferred:
        std::cout << "std::future_status::deferred" << std::endl;
        continue;
      }

      const int iResult = future.m_result.get();

      std::cout << "future returned [" << iResult << "] (removing!)" << std::endl;
      futures.erase(it);

      if (futures.size() < 1)
        break;

      it = futures.begin();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Cross-posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52361222/1014587)

Answer (score 7):

### Ugly typedef

I'm not a big fan of this:

```
typedef std::future<int> FutureResultInt;
```

It's not significantly shorter or easier to read, it doesn't isolate the user from an underlying type, and it only serves to slow down my reading every time I hit it.  That's somewhat subjective, of course, but I don't believe it adds value.  I'd be happier with it if it told us what it's *for*, rather than merely what it *is*.  I'm thinking of something like:

```
using TimerTaskResult = std::future<int>;
```

Now the name conveys something that's not just duplicating the standard name.

---

### Member initialization

My compiler warns me that the initializer list is in a misleading order:

```
203856.cpp:47:54: warning: ‘CFutureTest::m_start’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
203856.cpp:46:19: warning:   ‘FutureResultInt CFutureTest::m_result’ [-Wreorder]
203856.cpp:33:3: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
   CFutureTest(FutureResultInt&& fr)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'd also recommend *value-initializing* `m_result` rather than *default-constructing* followed by *move-assigning*:

```
  CFutureTest(FutureResultInt&& fr)
      : m_result{std::move(fr)}
      , m_start{std::chrono::system_clock::now()}
  {
  }
```

---

### Missing `case`

```
203856.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
203856.cpp:63:14: warning: enumeration value ‘ready’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
       switch (stat)
              ^
```

I like to have this warning enabled.  We could provide a minimal `case std::​future_status::​ready: break;`, or we could unify the control flow by changing the other branches from `continue` to `break` and inlining the following code into the `ready` case like this:

```
        switch (stat) {
        case std::future_status::timeout:
            if (future.GetAge() > 4000) {
                std::cout << "Thread has exceeded the time limit" << std::endl;
            }
            break;

        case std::future_status::deferred:
            std::cout << "std::future_status::deferred" << std::endl;
            break;

        case std::future_status::ready:
            {
                const int iResult = future.m_result.get();
                std::cout << "future returned [" << iResult << "] (removing!)" << std::endl;
                futures.erase(it);

                if (futures.empty()) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    it = futures.begin();
                }
            }
        }
```

Instead of returning to `futures.begin()` when we harvest a result, it's arguably better to keep going from the next element if there is one:

```
                it = futures.erase(it);
                if (it == futures.end()) {
                    if (futures.empty()) {
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        it = futures.begin();
                    }
                }
```

---

### Interleaved output

I know it's not part of your production code, but it's quite irritating to have the different threads' output interrupting each other mid-line.  We can provide a class to hold a lock while several items are written to a stream:

```
class LogStream
{
    static std::mutex mutex;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{mutex};
    std::ostream& stream{std::clog};

public:
    LogStream() {}
    template<typename T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(T&& t) { return stream << std::forward<T>(t); }
};

std::mutex LogStream::mutex;
```

And use it like this:

```
LogStream() << "ThreadFunc waiting for [" << iRand << "] ms ... " << std::endl;
```

---

### Be clear about units

I don't like this function name:

```
int GetAge() const
```

Perhaps change it to `getAgeMillis()`, or how about making it a template method? Like this:

```
template<typename TimeUnit = std::chrono::seconds>
int GetAge() const
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<TimeUnit>(now - m_start).count();
}
```

That also helps us deal with the very long lines that are a perennial problem with `duration_cast`.

---

### Avoid polling

This is the big one.  It's very power-inefficient to poll every 1ms to see whether you have any results; that's a bad thing on battery-powered systems, but it's just as important in a server farm.

What we need to do instead is have each finishing thread notify a condition variable.  When we're woken, we then examine all the futures, picking up any where `is_ready()`.

Unfortunately, that means we can't use `std::async()`, as its future isn't made ready until the called function has returned.  We'll need to implement our own version that can accept a `std::condition_variable&` to be notified *after* it sets the future's value.

You might be able to pick up some advice from Stack Overflow - here's a couple of starting points that might have something relevant:

- [Signaling main thread when `std::future` is ready to be retrieved](//stackoverflow.com/q/45852218)
- [How to implement `std::when_any` without polling?](//stackoverflow.com/q/44355747)